# regular expression help for parsing in alteryx

Tags: alteryx

I have a string (without doble qoutes) "2022-12-15 21:23:22 - a123456 (Remarks) 2022-12-15 22:12:22 - a123456 (Remarks) User acknowledgement time"

There are 2 date/time stamps in this string in need the date/time stamp appearing before User acknowledgement time. I am using regex `(\.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*User acknowledgement time)` my regex is capturing very first time stamp showing up in string but I need date/time stamp right before User acknowledgement time. Please help.

`(\.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*User acknowledgement time)`

I am expecting result as **2022-12-15 22:12:22 - a123456 (Remarks) User acknowledgement time**

but I am getting result **2022-12-15 21:23:22 - a123456 (Remarks) User acknowledgement time**

Comment: Why not just demand another date in your RegEx? As is, it's picking the first one it finds, and the 2nd gets lost with the wildcard

Comment: @johnjps111. Thanks, it helped to do similar and got more results.

Answer (score 0):

I think your group just needs to move.  Group 1 is what you are after:

```
.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*User acknowledgement time
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/b8wLrp/1)

Comment: I tried making 2 groups but still in first group I am getting date showing in beginning of the string not the one i need which is before User acknowledgement time